# Trading RAM by CPU (performance issue)

Tags: javascript, node.js, cpu, ram

I'm working with a program that deals with files, I can do several things like rename them, read the contents of them, etc.

Today I'm initializing it as follows:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  glob("path/for/files/**/*", {
    nodir: true
  }, (error, files) => {
    files = files.map((file) => {
      // properties like full name, basename, extension, etc.
    });
    resolve(files);
  });
});
```

So, i read the content of a specific directory, return all files within an array, and then use the Array.map to iterate over the array and change the paths for a object with properties.

Sometimes i work with 200.000 text files, so, this is becoming a problem because it is consuming too much RAM.

So, i want replace by a construction function with  lazy loading.. but i never did that before... so i'm looking for a help hand.

That's my code:

```
class File {
  constructor(path) {
    this.path = path;
  }

  extension() {
    return path.extname(this.path);
  }
  // etc
}
```

So, my main question is: should i only return the evaluation of the property, or should i replace it? Like this:

```
extension() {
  this.extension = path.extname(this.path);
}
```

I understand this is a trade off.. i'm going to trade the memory by cpu usage.

Thank you.

Comment: How about *not* using classes? Can't you store the file data in simple objects?

Comment: I'm storing the file in an array of objects, and which one is an object. I want change to classes to improve the memory usage.

Comment: @FXAMN Why do you believe that classes will reduce the memory usage?

Comment: @FXAMN Classes won't help you much there. I suggest using plain objects *without* prototype (created with `Object.create(null, properties)`). But then again, you won't ever see 200k elements in a view, better using lazy loading and even keeping *only* those in the view in memory, discarding the others (meaning, keeping the path string only and discarding other stat properties). (Btw, I don't know who downvoted, this is indeed a legit question, so I upvoted back.)

Comment: if you are using [this glob library](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) you may consider the `match` event and the `pause` method to create an iterator/generator that read *n* matches and returns them (one by one)

Comment: Would be this good for memory? @MargaretBloom Could you explain better?

Comment: I'm opening a bounty @MaxArt. Perhaps you could give me a answer with details?

Comment: RAM usage is controlled by the OS you can't manage it from within the browser. And there's no trade between RAM and CPU usage.

Comment: I'm using Node.js, or do you think i'm dealing with files in the browser?

Comment: @FAXAMN This is a hardware question. RAM and CPU usage are not interchangeable. So what if you are using Node.js?!

Comment: What argument is that? You are saying "you can't manage it from within the browser"... I'm not in the browser, i'm using Node.js. Now i'm storing a lot of objects in my memory with several properties... if i just evaluate instead of store in properties (replace by functions), i'm going change memory for CPU usage, since i'm going to need to call more than one time, instead of accessing file["property"].. it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @MaxArt what is the difference between Object.create(null, properties) from what i'm doing?

Comment: @FXAMN It's more lightweight. It probably won't completely solve your memory problems, but will help. You can verify that with `process.memoryUsage()`. The point is that you don't *need* a class, you can do everything with lightweight objects and static methods.

Comment: Really? I'm curious, why is lightweight?

Comment: use something like https://github.com/thlorenz/readdirp ?

Comment: i was thinking you could turn paths into a spereate array, and save a number with the file to refer to the index in the path array. it seems _full name, basename, extension_ could all be replaced by _name_, later slicing and dicing as-needed by the view. in short, you could likely cut your footprint by at least half with some clever re-arranging. Neither Object.create or classes will save you a lot of room, you need fewer bytes of data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reduce RAM usage, I suggest you store an extra meta-data file for each path, as follows:

1. Keep the paths in memory, or some of them, as necessary.
2. Save files properties to hard drive

```
files.forEach( (file) => { 
  // collect the properties you want for the file
  // ...
  var json = { path: file, extension: extension, .. }

  // mark the metadata file so you can access it later, for example: put it in the same path with a suffix
  var metaFile = path + '_meta.json';
  fs.writeFile(metaFile, JSON.stringify(json), (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
  }); 
});
```

Now all the meta data is on hard drive. This way, I believe, you trade memory for disk space and CPU calls.

3. If you wish to get properties for a file, just read and `JSON.parse` its corresponding meta data file.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to trade CPU for space. Just walk the tree and process files as they're found. The space needed for walking the tree is proportional to the tree depth if it's done depth first. This is almost certainly has same overhead as just creating the list of paths in your existing code.

For directory walking, the [node.js FAQ](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/file-system/how-to-search-files-and-directories-in-nodejs/) recommends [node-findit](https://github.com/substack/node-findit). The documentation there is pretty clear. Your code will look something like:

```
var finder = require('findit')(root_directory);
var path = require('path');
var basenames = [];

finder.on('file', function (file, stat) {
  basenames.push(path.basename(file));
  // etc
}
```

Or you can wrap the captured values in an object if you like.

Answer (score 0):

If you store only path property NodeJS class instance take for your example `200k * (path.length * 2 + 6)` bytes memory.

If you want to use lazy loading for basenames, extenstions etc use lazy getters

```
class File {
  constructor(path) {
     this.path = path;
     this._basename = null;
     this._extname = null;
  }
  get extname() {
     return this._extname || (this._extname = path.extname(this.path));
  }
  get basename() {
     return this._basename || (this._basename = path.basename(this.path));
  }
}
```